# Options to expensive bandpass, notch and cut-off filters

Tags: filters

I would like to experiment with different kinds of bandpass, notch and cut-off color filters, but when I look at the pricing on sites like

https://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/bandpass-filters/

http://www.omegafilters.com/products/filters/bandpass.html

https://www.newport.com/c/bandpass-filters

I find that I wont get far with my budget.

I therefore wonder if someone has alternative suggestions when it comes to equipment or knows a vendor that produces similar filters but in cheaper plastic or other materials.

Comment: This seems like it might could be and xy question. What is it that you want to accomplish with these filters? What *photographic* problem are you trying to solve that you think these filters will help?

Comment: It's in experimental purposes, to gain insight on what parts of the spectrum is more or less interesting compared to other parts. And simply go get some unique pictures.

Comment: What exactly is your budget? The first page has dozens of filters available for $25-50. $25 doesn't seem unreasonable for a single filter. They also have some that are thousands of dollars, but some of those are rather exotic things that your cameras sensors can't pick up like Deep UV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own filters by following the example of Frederic Wratten and his parter C. E. K. Mees. They were the master filter makers of all times. In those days, filters were hollow glass cells filled with liquids. These two perfected dying gelatin and floating the concoction on water. They then scoped up a flat colored gelatin filter with a wire frame from underneath.  The dried gelatin filter was cut to size and many were sandwiched between flat glass sheets. So famous and accurate were these filters that Kodak purchased the company in 1912. Today, filters bare the name Wratten when they correspond to his recipe and catalog number.  You too can make narrow cut filters in your basement.